# IOS UILabel sizeToFit

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uilabel, sizetofit

I want to use the sizeToFit method to display a variable amount of text in a UILabel. It works perfectly to show all the text...but is there a way to use sizeToFit up to a certain maximum frame height.

In other words, I want to have sizeToFit increase the frame size up to a certain point, so that more text is shown, but not necessarily all the text.

Is there some work around or method that could do that?

Thanks!
xcode 4.3.3

Comment: Can you show the code you are using now?

Comment: Can't you just reduce the frame's height if sizeToFit makes it larger than your maximum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can get the dynamic width and set it to the label using font size and text string..